# Batch File: FOR /F doesn't work as expected

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

I have an issue with reading lines from a *.txt file in batch script to get a list of files.
If my file contain something like

```
File does not exist: release\devpath\readme.txt
File does not exist: release\mainline\readme!!!.txt
2 errors.
```

and my batch is

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set count_to_sync=-1
for /f  "tokens=*" %%i in (bubu.txt) do (
    set line=%%i
    echo %%i

    if "!line:~0,9!" == "MD5 FAIL:"  (
        set /A count_to_sync+=1
        set list[!count_to_sync!]=!line:~10!
    )
    if "!line:~0,20!" == "File does not exist:"  (
        set list[!count_to_sync!]=!line:~21!
        set /A count_to_sync+=1
    )
)

IF "%count_to_sync%" == "-1" (
    ECHO Nothing to sync
) ELSE (
    ECHO Files to sync
    for /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%s in ('set list[') do (
        echo %%s
    )
)
```

The output is

```
File does not exist: release\devpath\readme.txt
File does not exist: release\mainline\readme.txt
2 errors.
Files to sync
release\devpath\readme.txt
release\mainline\readme.txt
```

and the '!!!' from second line is missing.

I know that if I remove `SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION`  from batch the output will be

```
File does not exist: release\devpath\readme.txt
File does not exist: release\mainline\readme!!!.txt
2 errors.
```

First part is OK, but the extraction will not work because delayed expansion is disabled.

How I can get the correct output? 
Thank you

**UPDATE**

The input file with all types of lines

```
File does not exist: release\devpath\readme.txt
File does not exist: release\mainline\readme!!!.txt
MD5 FAIL: exf.exe
2 errors.
```

**UPDATE**

I need this script to sync changed files based on the output of 'exf.exe' used to check the integrity of folder based on md5 checksum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the specifications of a problem are not *described*, but based *on examples*, we can make assumptions that may or may not be correct. My assumption is that you want *the last token* of the lines in your text file, so this is a possible (and much simpler) solution:

**EDIT**: I changed my original method for a simpler one.

```
@echo off
setlocal

set "msg=Nothing to sync"
(for /F "tokens=3,5" %%a in (bubu.txt) do (
   set "msg=Files to sync"
   if "%%b" neq "" (echo %%b) else echo %%a
)) > list.txt 

echo %msg%
type list.txt
```

Comment: Your assumptions is correct. Nice approach, tomorow I will test :)

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\q35477317.txt"
ECHO Files to sync
FOR /f "usebackqtokens=4*delims=: " %%a IN ("%filename1%") DO ECHO(%%b

GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the setting of `sourcedir` to suit your circumstances.

I used a file named `q35477317.txt` containing your data for my testing.

It's not clear why you've taken your approach - is there something you haven't told us?

---

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\q35477317.txt"
ECHO Files to sync
FOR /f "usebackqtokens=1*delims=:" %%a IN ("%filename1%") DO (
 FOR /f "tokens=*" %%c IN ("%%b") DO ECHO(%%c
)
GOTO :EOF
```

Easily fixed once we get the full story...

Comment: if you look in my script, in the imput file exist two tipes of lines which i need, one is starting with  'File does not exist:' and another starts with 'MD5 FAIL:' . My fault is that i didn't provide all types of lines in the input.  now is updated

Comment: usebackqtokens=4* will not catch 'MD5 FAIL: exf.exe'

Comment: it will be enough fast? with for in for

Comment: Yes - easy way is to test it, but you'll not see a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need something like that:

```
@ECHO OFF
rem SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set count_to_sync=-1
for /f  "tokens=*" %%i in (bubu.txt) do (
    set line=%%i
    echo %%i

    SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

    if "!line:~0,9!" == "MD5 FAIL:"  (
        set /A count_to_sync+=1
        set list[!count_to_sync!]=!line:~10!
    )
    if "!line:~0,20!" == "File does not exist:"  (
        set list[!count_to_sync!]=!line:~21!
        set /A count_to_sync+=1
    )

    ENDLOCAL
)

IF "%count_to_sync%" == "-1" (
    ECHO Nothing to sync
) ELSE (
    ECHO Files to sync
    for /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%s in ('set list[') do (
        echo %%s
    )
)
```

Comment: unfortunately this approach raise 'Maximum setlocal recursion level reached.'

Comment: @vasilenicusor I do apologize. It works with these two lines in bubu.txt on my windows 7

Comment: It's true, but the input file is not always with exact 2 lines, is dinamic, contains all files changed from a repository

Comment: @vasilenicusor I have edited script according to http://superuser.com/a/943598 and now I hope it will work with any number of lines (tested wil 5000+ lines).